# How to convert an int to a list?

Tags: python, list

I have some code that might return either a single int, or a list. When it returns an int, I need to convert it into a list that contains only the int.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
newValue = list(retValue)
```

Apparently I can't do `list(some int)` because ints are not iterable. Is there another way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I have some code that might return either a single int, or a list." **Why does it behave this way**? Is it your code? Why not adjust it to always return the same kind of thing? Either there's a good reason why it returns an int (instead of a list with 1 int in it), or there isn't...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

define your own function:

```
 def mylist(x):
    if isinstance(x,(list,tuple)):
        return x
    else:
        return [x]


>>> mylist(5)
[5]
>>> mylist([10])
[10]
```

Comment: The problem with casting [x] is, if the x is a list already, this will make it a nested list, which is not desired. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Jimster I updated the solution, in case if the number is list itself.

Comment: `if not isinstance(x,(tuple,list)):return [x]`  ... maybe

Comment: Hate to say it, but this isn't very... Pythonic. Duck typing means checking behaviour rather than isinstance, so consider using len(x)==1. But it's better to always return a list from a function that can return lists, so that you can deal with that appropriately. If you sometimes call it with one value and sometimes with a list, then have two implementations; one for singles and one for lists. Making one thing do two jobs is the path to complexity.

Comment: Second solution is great but `list([x])` is doing absolutely nothing since `[x]` is already a list and you are just converting it into a list again, but it remains as `[x]`. Remove the `list` call and it will be better.

Answer (score 7):

In Python, duck typing is preferable - don't test for a specific type, just test whether it supports the method you need ("I don't care if it's a duck, so long as it quacks").

```
def make_list(n):
    if hasattr(n, '__iter__'):
        return n
    else:
        return [n]

a = make_list([1,2,3])    # => [1,2,3]
b = make_list(4)          # => [4]
```

Comment: +1 for duck-typing...“If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck.”

Comment: +1 for duck typing, _but_, you can get the same behavior in (what I think is) a prettier way with [`isinstance(n, collections.Iterable)`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Iterable). Also, the OP asks for lists; to get list-like things but eliminate generator-like and dict-like things, [`collections.Sequence`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Sequence) is handy.

Comment: @senderle: You should post that as an answer, because it really is the ideal answer to this question. (Well, except for Karl Knechtel's comment—if the OP owns the function that returns a list or an int, he should probably change it to just always return a list…)

Answer (score 2):

```
if isinstance(x,list): return x
else: return [x]
```

That's it.

Of course, this won't deal intelligently with other iterable types, but it's not clear that you want to treat all iterables as if they were lists (maybe you do, maybe you don't).

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert the variable to an int. If it is already an int this is a no-op. If it is a list then this raises a TypeError.

```
try:
    return [int(x)]
except TypeError:
    return x
```

Though using exceptions for flow control is generally frowned upon if the exceptional circumstance has a high probability of occurring. This is because processing exceptions is quite a lengthy task.

The other way is to use the `isinstance` operator.

```
if isinstance(x, list):
    return x
else:
    return [x]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
listInt = intVal if isinstance(intVal,list) else [intVal]
```

this will always return a list if value is not a list.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

This is really just a variation on [Hugh Bothwell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11422648/577088)'s answer, but... if you want state-of-the-art duck typing, you can get the semantics of `hasattr(rval, '__iter__')` in a more attractive package with `isinstance(rval, collections.Iterable)`. So...

```
def wrap_in_iterable(x):
    if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
        return x
    else:
        return [x]
```

Also, perhaps you want a *list*, and not just an iterable; to get list-like things but eliminate generator-like and dict-like things, `collections.Sequence` is handy. (Just don't pass an infinite generator to this function.)

```
def convert_to_sequence(x):
    if isinstance(x, collections.Sequence):
        return x
    elif isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
        return list(x)
    else
        return [x]
```

These work because `collections.Sequence` and `collection.Iterable` define [`__subclasshook__`](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__)s that perform the appropriate `hasattr` checks.

Finally, at the risk of being boring -- if you have control over the returning function, just return a one-item list if possible.